# jqgrid edit cell and save to database

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid and trying to edit a cell and update the value to table in database, but im missing something and couldnt make it work. please help me to correct if im missing something.below is the code for your reference. please help. thanks in advance.

**HTML**

```
    $qr="SELECT id,`emp_id`,`emp_name`, `att_date`, `emp_join_date`, `intime`,`outtime`,`Total_Hours`,`OT Hours`,`Status` FROM `db_emp_attendance` WHERE Status='Absent' and att_date='2017-04-01'";
    $q = mysql_query($qr);
    $rows = array();
    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
        $rows[] = $r;
    }
    $json_data=json_encode($rows);
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script type="text/ecmascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/ecmascript" src="jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/ecmascript" src="grid.locale-en.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="jquery-ui.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="ui.jqgrid.css"/>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>

    <table id="rowed5"></table>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    var lastsel2
    jQuery("#rowed5").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    height: 400,
    autowidth: true,
    colNames:['ID','Emp ID','Name', 'Join Date','Attendance Date', 'Time In','Time Out','Total Hours','OT Hours','Status','leave_type'],
    colModel:[
    {name:'id',index:'id', width:75,align:"center",key: true},
    {name:'emp_id',index:'emp_id', width:75,align:"center"},
    {name:'emp_name',index:'emp_name', width:150,align:"left"},
    {name:'emp_join_date',index:'emp_join_date', width:150,align:"center"},
    {name:'att_date',index:'att_date', width:100, align:"center"},      
    {name:'intime',index:'intime', width:80,align:"center"},        
    {name:'outtime',index:'outtime', width:80,align:"center"},
    {name:'Total_Hours',index:'Total_Hours', width:80,align:"center"},
    {name:'OT Hours',index:'OT Hours', width:80,align:"center"},
    {name:'Status',index:'Status', width:150,align:"center"},
{name:'leave_type',index:'leave_type', width:150, sortable:false,editable: true,
    edittype: "select",
    editoptions: {
    value: "SickLeave:SickLeave;DayOff:DayOff;Vacation:Vacation"}
    }
    ],

    onSelectRow: function(id){
    if(id && id!==lastsel2){
    jQuery('#rowed5').jqGrid('restoreRow',lastsel2);
    jQuery('#rowed5').jqGrid('editRow',id,true);
    lastsel2=id;
    }
    },
    editurl:'update.php',
    caption: "Attendance"

    });
    var mydata2 =<?PHP echo $json_data;?>;
    for(var i=0;i < mydata2.length;i++)
     jQuery("#rowed5").jqGrid('addRowData',mydata2[i].id,mydata2[i]);
     </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**DB UPDATE PHP FILE**

```
    if($_POST['oper']=='edit')
     {
        $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
        $leave_type = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['leave_type']);
        $sql = "UPDATE db_emp_attendance SET leave_type = '$leave_type' WHERE id = '$id'";
        mysql_query($sql);
    }
```

Comment: i found a solution and now it is updating in database. i had to add `cellEdit : true,`
 `cellsubmit : 'remote',`
 `cellurl : 'update.php', `, now i have one more problem, once the cell is edited the value is saved in the DB, after reloading the grid the value disappears, but it is available in DB. how can i show the value from DB for the edited cells after reloading? please help.

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution and now it is updating in database. i had to add cellEdit : true, cellsubmit : 'remote', cellurl : 'update.php'